# how to edit homepage

Tags: themes, homepage

[image]i am learning html and php from scratch, 
 i had upload a wordpress website, all ok, but i have problem with some editing, 
means i coluld not find which file i have to edit.
i search index.php but in index.php file i did not find texts that i want to edit.

i am using education base theme, my website `http://saraswati-school.com/`

i also read official documents of 'education base' theme, 
please help me, which in which file i can find text that i want to edit.

i want to edit text in red rectangle in upper image.
thanks

website

```
http://saraswati-school.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

If the theme doesn't have a dedicated admin page for customizing home page, most probably that text should be customizable via WordPress customizer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find your homepage in

> Dashboard / Pages / All pages

Your homepage can be find with the " — Front Page" label

Comment: thanks dear for answer, but in homepage i didn't find content that i wnd to edit, can you help me on teamviewer or skype

Comment: Check your widget section, maybe the content is generated from a widget

Comment: i checked widget, run notepad++ and ack-grep in linux for searching specefic text in whole website but i did't find text that i want to edit,
also try to find class and related file with inspect element, but not successed